# Secure Articulate files

Tags: secure-coding

I have created some eLearning content with Articulate Story-line. And converted as IOS app. I want to secure my files created with Articulate when I publish and give the content as an Offline app.

Please help me to get this done. I don't know how to secure these html files.

Thanks in advance.

This is for an app, loading all the HTML files created with Articulate Story line.

Comment: Otherwise please help me to protect my videos and images from others to use it.

Comment: or if they download it should not work.. pls suggest me a way to do this..